# Gulp recompilation of Less files restarts IIS Express in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: less, gulp, iis-express, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Gulp which is watching for changes in my Less files.  If a change is detected it compiles the Less files and creates the css for my application.

When the application is debugging in VS2015, and I modify my Less files causing a recompile of the css, IIS Express restarts my web application.

This causes a break in the work flow as it takes time to start up.  I would not have expected this to happen as it doesn't normally when modifying plain css.

This happens whether I have it configured via the task runner or the command line.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

**Update**
After further digging, I have found that omitting:

```
gulp.task('clean-styles', function (cb) {
    del([config.fontsout,
         config.cssout, 
         config.lessout + '/*.css'], cb);
});
```

Seems to prevent IIS resetting every time I update css.  I still don't know whether this is expected behaviour or if I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: any update here? running into same issue :(